Python implementation for real-time drawing of rectangles on Windows system desktops
import win32gui, win32ui, win32api, win32con
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)
dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(dc)
hwnd = win32gui.WindowFromPoint((0,0))
monitor = (0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1))
red = win32api.RGB(255, 0, 0) # Red

past_coordinates = monitor
while True:
    mx = 100
    my = 100
    rect = win32gui.CreateRoundRectRgn(*past_coordinates, 2 , 2)
    # 刷新部分区域的内容
    win32gui.RedrawWindow(hwnd, past_coordinates, rect, win32con.RDW_INVALIDATE)
    # 绘制指定像素点
    # for x in range(200):#200 控制边长
    #     if x<100:
    #         y = x
    #     # win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+x, my, red)#绘制上横线
    #     win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+y, my+150, red)#绘制下横线
    #     # win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx, my+y, red) #绘制左竖线
    #     win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+100, my+y, red)#绘制右竖线
    for x in range(200): #200控制矩形长边
        if x<100:  #控制矩形短边
           y = x
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+x, my, red)#绘制上横线
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+x, my+100, red)#绘制下横线
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx, my+y, red)#绘制左竖线
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+200, my+y, red)#绘制右竖线
    long_bian = 300
    short_bian =200
    for x in range(long_bian): #200控制矩形长边
        if x<short_bian:  #控制矩形短边
           y = x
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+x, my, red)#绘制上横线
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+x, my+short_bian, red)#绘制下横线
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx, my+y, red)#绘制左竖线
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, mx+long_bian, my+y, red)#绘制右竖线
    # 记录待刷新区域
    # past_coordinates = (mx-20, my-20, mx+20, my+20)


I tried to draw a rectangle using the method of setting pixel points, but I couldn't refresh the last drawn pattern, and the speed was also relatively slow. I searched online and found that it is possible to set a Windows transparent window to achieve this, but I am not familiar with the pywin32 library and cannot implement it
I tried to capture the Windows screen in real-time while drawing the results with OpenCV and displaying thementer image description here
But this nested window has appeared，I hope to find a different way to achieve real-time drawing of rectangles on the Windows desktop
